# Couchbase query filtering by tag in an array

Tags: sql, couchbase, sql++

I have a author bucket. And in this bucket I keep the author infos and author's articles. I want to select the articles that have the tags I want from the author bucket.

I have tried this but I could not find how to do the filtering.

```
SELECT art.* FROM author AS a 
UNNEST a.articles AS art
WHERE art.tags = 'History'
```

This is author bucket:

```
{
  "about": {
    "name": "sassa",
    "userName": "sassatur"
  },
  "articles": [
    {
      "authorId": [
        "8c7ba33e-0674-4d99-bfad-29d144028bc9"
      ],
      "claps": [],
      "comments": [],
      "content": {
        "articleType": "HTML",
        "data": "My First Article"
      },
      "id": "71d6fa22-61be-4a93-8e86-8d569080da97",
      "publishStatus": "UNLISTED",
      "statistic": {
        "articleId": "71d6fa22-61be-4a93-8e86-8d569080da97",
        "views": [
          1602683127039,
          1602683148270
        ]
      },
      "tags": [
        "Art, History"
      ],
      "title": "Culture"
    },
    {
      "authorId": [
        "8c7ba33e-0674-4d99-bfad-29d144028bc9"
      ],
      "claps": [],
      "comments": [],
      "content": {
        "articleType": "HTML",
        "data": "My First Article"
      },
      "id": "81d6fa22-63be-4a93-8e86-8d569080da97",
      "publishStatus": "UNLISTED",
      "statistic": {
        "views": [
          1602683127039,
          1602683148270
        ]
      },
      "tags": [
        "Art"
      ],
      "title": "Culture"
    }
  ],
  "id": "8c7ba33e-0674-4d99-bfad-29d144028bc9",
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`ANY/IN/SATISFIES`](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/collectionops.html#collection-op-any), like so:

```
SELECT art.* FROM author AS a 
UNNEST a.articles AS art
WHERE ANY x IN art.tags SATISFIES x == 'Art' END;
```

This works for 'Art' in your example, but not 'History' because of the way you are storing tags. It's an array, but it appears to have a single(?) item with comma-separated values. So, instead of `"tags": ["Art,History"]`, I would recommend: `"tags": ["Art","History"]` instead, and then it will work.

However, if you are stuck with the comma-separate string, you can use [`SPLIT`](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/stringfun.html#fn-str-split) and [`ARRAY_CONTAINS`](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/arrayfun.html#fn-array-contains) as well:

```
SELECT art.* FROM author AS a 
UNNEST a.articles AS art
WHERE ANY x IN art.tags SATISFIES ARRAY_CONTAINS(SPLIT(x,", "), 'History') END;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is exactly the query I was looking for.